# Many To Many Relationships not updating in Sqlite Extensions

Tags: sqlite-net-extensions

Please pardon the wall of code, but I need to set the stage....

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentStaff))]        
    public List<Staff> Teachers { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentGuardian))]
    public List<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
 }

  public class Guardian
     {
         [PrimaryKey]
         public string Id { get; set; }
         public string Name{get;set;}       

         [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentGuardian))]
         public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }

public class Staff
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentStaff))]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentStaff
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Student))]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Staff))]
    public string StaffId { get; set; }
}

 public class StudentGuardian
    {
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Student))]
        public string StudentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(typeof(Guardian))]
        public string GuardianId { get; set; }
}
```

Given those classes how should I insert the Students, Staff and Guardians into the database while maintaining the relationships?  I should note that the server returns populated Student records, so that is my starting point.

I tried `conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChidlren(student);`...that inserted the student, the studentstaff and the studentguardian records but not the actual staff or guardian.
I tried 
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student);`
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student.Teachers);`
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student.Guardians);`
Oddly that ended up with staff, guardian and teachers inserted but neither of the intersection tables had any data...

--Update---
I just tried
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student.Teachers);`
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student.Guardians);`
`conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student);`
And it worked perfectly...the question is why?  Why does a many to many seem to be dependent on operation order?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite-Net Extensions requires that all the objects have been assigned an unique ID to establish the relationships. With `AutoIncrement` primary keys this means that all objects have been already inserted in the database.

The order may also affect if the inverse relationships have not been set, it's usually a good idea to set the inverse relationship or set those attributes as `ReadOnly` to avoid side effects.

That being said, SQLite-Net Extensions provides utility methods for helping with this task. In this case, you could make use of cascade operations to perform a single insert. To enable cascade operations, define the `CascadeOperations` property of the relationship attribute:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentStaff), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]        
    public List<Staff> Teachers { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentGuardian), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All))]
    public List<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
 }

  public class Guardian
  {
      [PrimaryKey]
      public string Id { get; set; }
      public string Name{get;set;}       

      [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentGuardian), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All, ReadOnly = true))]
      public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
  }

public class Staff
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(StudentStaff), CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All, ReadOnly = true))]
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

In this sample I also included `ReadOnly` property to make `Guardian` and `Staff` relationships to `Student` a read-only property so SQLite-Net Extensions will ignore this relationship when saving the objects to the database.

Then, you can use the `recursive` parameter of any SQLite-Net Extensions method to `true`:

```
conn.InsertOrReplaceWithChildren(student, recursive: true);
```

SQLite-Net Extensions will handle inverse relationships and relationship loops correctly.

Comment: Hmmm I like the readonly, I'll give the rest a whirl and let you know.  I'm not 100% sure why you mentioned Autoincrement keys..my samples have none of those at all.